# Letting Stack find C headers used with library (FFI)

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm creating a wrapper around a pre-compiled C library (GLFW, I know bindings exist, it's for figuring out how to use the Haskell FFI in a practical setting), and I haven't been able to figure out how to get Stack to include the C headers in the build.

This means that my build *works*, but I get a number of warnings about implicit function declarations during compilation. e.g.:

```
C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Temp\ghc23648_0\ghc_5.c:8:61: error:
    warning: implicit declaration of function 'glfwInit' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    8 | HsInt32 ghczuwrapperZC1ZCmainZCMainZCglfwInit(void) {return glfwInit();}
    [...]
    8 | HsInt32 ghczuwrapperZC1ZCmainZCMainZCglfwInit(void) {return glfwInit();}
```

I figured out how to add C libraries in package.yaml with `extra-lib-dirs:` and `extra-libraries:`. Unfortunately, when I browse the internet, the field it suggests for adding headers in Cabal, `includes:`, doesn't actually get recognized by Stack:

```
C:\Users\****\Workspace\Testing\ffitest\package.yaml: Ignoring unrecognized field $.executables.ffitest-exe.includes
```

Just to be sure, I tried to use the same field in stack.yaml instead, just in case it would be recognized there. It causes the same error.

What is the appropriate way to include C header files in a Stack project, assuming there is one?

---

**System info**

Windows 10
Stack version 2.9.1 (GHC 9.0.2)
Using MinGW64 GLFW 3.3.8 pre-compiled libraries